# Restaurant Bookings available slots with different intervals

Tags: mysql, sql

Here i have table for bookings in restaurant . I want to know available time slots for new bookings even 10 min difference available between starttime and endtime

Please help me to retrieve available timings  for restaurant tables

Bookings table like this,

```
booking id    reastaurantid tableid noofpersons starttime             endtime 
1               1              1       1        2014-05-02 04:30:00  2014-05-02 05:00:00
2               1              1       1        2014-05-02 05:30:00  2014-05-02 06:30:00
3               1              1       1        2014-05-02 10:00:00  2014-05-02 10:30:00
4               1              1       1        2014-05-02 11:00:00  2014-05-02 11:30:00
5               1              1       1        2014-05-02 12:00:00  2014-05-02 12:30:00
6               1              1       1        2014-05-02 17:30:00  2014-05-02 18:30:00
```

I want free time slots  until end of the day .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have another approach to offer. It joins the booking table on itself and selects for each booking's endtime all starttimes of other bookings which are greater. This means it gets you a list of all subsequent bookings for each booking. If you have that you only have to group by the booking and select the minimum starttime from the subsequent bookings. This should give you the start time for the next booking for each booking. Then you can easily calculate the difference.

```
SELECT e.booking_id,e.endtime, min(s.starttime) start_next_booking
FROM bookings e
    JOIN bookings s ON e.restaurantid=s.restaurantid AND e.tableid=s.tableid AND s.booking_id<>e.booking_id AND e.endtime<s.starttime
GROUP BY e.booking_id,e.endtime
```

I haven't tested it but I think it should do.

Answer (score 0):

First let's define a subquery which will be used in the main one

```
select @num:=@num+1 as row,
       start_time,
       end_time,
       booking_id
from the_table t, (select @num:=0) sess
order by start_time
```

Then the sql which uses the subquery

```
select 
  sub1.end_time as free_inverval_start,
  sub2.start_time as free_inverval_end
from (sub_query) sub1 
     join (sub_query) sub2 on sub1.row=sub2.row-1
                          and sub1.end_time<2.start_time
```

I skip the restaurant and table ids but you can extend the logic to include them